# c++: for not working as intended

Tags: c++, for-loop

My question is when I run the code,and call for the list,so I press 3,nothing happens and it just skips over the code in for(). Why does this occur and how can I fix it?
Simple code would be welcome.I am now to this.

The first two int before the main checks if the student is qualified for the school,or not.i tested those and they are working great.

The struct describes a student.He/She has a name(nev),marks (bacmagy,bacrom,bacmat,bacvalasz).A boolean value(langexam) is present,to represent is the student has a language exam or not.

bsiker is true,if the formula in  calculateBac turns out to be true.
atmente is true,if bsiker and langexam are both true.

The listing would spit out the name,bsiker and atmente.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int atmegye(bool elso, bool masodik){
    if (elso && masodik)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

int calculateBac(double magy, double mat, double rom, double val){
    double osszeg = magy + mat + rom + val;
    osszeg = osszeg / 4;
    if (magy < 5 || mat < 5 || rom < 5 || val < 5 || osszeg < 6)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}

int main(){

    struct diak{
        char nev[32];
        bool langexam, atmente, bsiker;
        double bacmagy, bacrom, bacmat, bacvalasz, bac;
    };

    diak v[150];
    bool cap = false;
    int opcio;
    int j, n = 0;
    int i = 0;

    do{
        cout << "\n Welcome. \n 1-new studient \n 2-Change a studient's details \n 3-List \n 4-Exit \n";
        cin >> opcio;

        switch (opcio){
            case 4:{
                return 0;
            }
            case 1:{
                cout << "Please give the name of the student: ";
                cin >> v[i].nev;
                cout << "Hungarian mark: ";
                cin >> v[i].bacmagy;
                cout << "Romanian mark: ";
                cin >> v[i].bacrom;
                cout << "Maths mark: ";
                cin >> v[i].bacmat;
                cout << "Optional mark: ";
                cin >> v[i].bacvalasz;

                cout << " Do you have a language exam? Please respond with 1 or 0: ";
                cin >> v[i].langexam;
                v[i].bsiker = calculateBac(v[i].bacmagy, v[i].bacrom, v[i].bacmat, v[i].bacvalasz);
                v[i].atmente = atmegye(v[i].bsiker, v[i].langexam);
                i = i + 1;
                i = n;
                cout << n;

                break;
                }

            case 3: {
                for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
                    cout << v[i].nev << " " << v[i].bsiker << " " << endl;
                break;
            }
        }
    }while (opcio != 5);
}
```

Comment: It's a bit hard to read at the moment. Please spend a bit of time indenting it and you'll get better responses.

Comment: Where do you change `n`?

Comment: As Kevin says, n is always 0.  for(;;) is indeed working as expected.  `n` is probably not the right name for such an apparently crucial variable.  Or maybe `v.size()` is what should be used in place of `n`.  Using `v.size()` would indeed make the student count fool-proof.

Comment: Why returning `bool` from `calculateBac` while you declared it to return `int`?

Comment: if I use v.size() it results in this compiling error:E:\Programok\pls.cpp|73|error: request for member 'size' in 'v', which is of non-class type 'main()::diak [150]'|

Comment: `v.size()` is for `std::vector`, not an array. You probably should use a vector, though.

Comment: sorry.  Your program is in C.   Your students list should be in a vector. Don't they teach you C++ at school?

Comment: And,Raindrop7,it is a bit stupid on my part,thanks for pointing this out,but if I change it to bool,the result is the same.

Comment: Well,Michaël Roy I tought this was c++ :P At least that's what the teacher is supposed to teach.

Comment: Also `main`should return value and `j` is redundant.

Comment: Use std::vector<diak>.  And use std::string for struct member nev.  There is much more in the C++ standard library than std::cin and std::cout.

Comment: For example, this line `cin >> v[i].nev;` will cause an out of bounds condition if the sudent's name is over 50 characters long.  That's the next bug waiting for you. By using a string (and cropping it if necessary), this would not happen.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting string.It helped a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is wrong:

```
            i = n;
```

it should be:

```
            n = i;
```

Your code is just undoing the `i = i + 1;` line that precedes it.

Comment: only applies if option 1 is run first;-)

Comment: @Harry If option 1 isn't run, the array of students is empty and `n = 0` is fine.

Comment: so right you are! i shall read the whole thing next time :-)

Answer (score 1):

n is initialized as 0 and never set to any other value. Therefore your for loop is not supposed to run any iteration

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the for loop's conditional. You initialized the value of n to 0, and that value never seems to change. The variable i is also initialized to 0 inside the for loop. When the user chooses option 3, the for loop conditional ( 0 < 0) is evaluated which is false, so the for loop is skipped every time. So, to fix this problem, you need to update the value of n somewhere in your code, or you need to change your conditional statement. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I know this probably won't help for your assignment, but here's *a* (one of many) way to handle this is a more c++-like manner, and without using OOP.

The standard library and the c++ type system give us plenty of useful tools to **avoid writing bugs** in the first place (that's really nice!), and find the one that are left at compile-time (saves a ton of time!).  That's what the biggest difference between c and c++ is, and it is a very important one.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>

// fixed-size record to save in data file, for example.
struct diak{
    char nev[32];
    bool langexam, atmente, bsiker;
    double bacmagy, bacrom, bacmat, bacvalasz, bac;
};

void atmegye(diak& student)
{
    student.atmente = student.bsiker && student.langexam;
}

void calculateBac(diak& student)  // computes grades average, checks if passed.
{
    double osszeg = student.bacmagy + student.bacmat + student.bacrom + student.bacvalasz;
    student.bac = osszeg / 4.0;

    student.bsiker = student.bacmagy >= 5
                  && student.bacrom >= 5
                  && student.bacmat >= 5
                  && student.bacvalasz >= 5
                  && student.bac >= 5;       // this last test unnecessary, but rules are rules.
}

void AddNewStudent(std::ostream& os, std::istream& is, std::vector<diak>& students)
{
    diak new_student;
    std::string temp;
    while(temp.empty())
    {
        os << "Student name: ";  
        is >> temp;   // using a temp buffer avoids out of bounds errors
    }

    if (temp.length() >= sizeof(new_student.nev))
        temp.resize(sizeof(new_student.nev) - 1);
    strcpy(new_student.nev, temp.c_str());

    // input values below SHOULD be validated for range (0-100)
    // or whatever makes sense for your school.

    os << "Hungarian mark: ";  is >> new_student.bacmagy;
    os << "Romanian mark: ";   is >> new_student.bacrom;
    os << "Maths mark: ";      is >> new_student.bacmat;
    os << "Optional mark: ";   is >> new_student.bacvalasz;

    // example validation.  Validating user input is the worst!
    // above ^^^ grades ^^^ can use a common function for validation.
    for(;;)
    {
        os << " Do you have a language exam? Please respond with 1 or 0:";
        is >> temp;
        if (temp == "0")
        {
             new_student.langexam = false;
             break;
        }
        if (temp == "1")
        {
             new_student.langexam = true;
             break;
        }

       // not a valid entry, try again!
    }

    calculateBac(new_student);
    atmegye(new_student);

    students.push_back(new_student);
}

void EditSudent(std::ostream& os, std::istream& is, std::vector<diak>& students)
{
    // query which student then edit using streams 'os' and 'is' for i/o.
}   

// could also be used to write to file...
void PrintStudents(std::ostream& os, const std::vector<diak>& students)
{
    // maybe by printing a student number you could reuse this 
    // function from EditStudent()...
    //
    // At the same time, it is only 2 lines of code.  You decide.

    for(size_t i = 0; i < students.size(); i++)
        os << students[i].nev << " " << students[i].bsiker << "\n";
    os.flush();
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<diak> students;  // could also be an std::list<>

    while(true)  // 1 less line of code than do {...} while, and easier to read. 
    {
        int opcio = 0;
        std::cout << "\n Welcome." 
                     "\n 1-new studient" 
                     "\n 2-Change a studient's details" 
                     "\n 3-List "
                     "\n 4-Exit \n";
        std::cin >> opcio;

        switch (opcio)
        {
            case '1':
                AddNewStudent(std::cout, std::cin, students);
                break;

            case 2:
                EditSudent(std::cout, std::cin, students);   // << queries student and edit that
                break;

            case 3:
                PrintStudents(std::cout, students);
                break;

            case 4:
                return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Note how the tasks are very well delimited into their own function, this also helps finding bugs faster, as it makes the code easier to read and reason about (the famous divide and conquer strategy).

Having the students array (or list) as a single entity simplifies its management, no extra variable to keep up to date, etc...

In a more serious application, the input validation would be best done using a template, and would give the user an escape character so he could cancel adding the new student at any time.